# Evaluate $\int_0^1\int_p^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt{1-y^6}} dydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been working on this sum for a while. The question asks to evaluate the double integral.
$$\int_0^1\int_p^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt{1-y^6}} dydx$$
where $p$ is equal to $x^2$. I know that I have to solve the $y$ integral first and then the $x$. But I don't know how to solve the root integral. Applying the formula $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$ where $t=y^3$ isn't working. Any ideas as to how I must proceed with the integral? Once I get the integral, I must substitute the limits and then the integral would be in terms of $x$ and I must integrate it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the order of integration.  You can do this by drawing the region of integration and seeing that the integral is just

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^6}} \, \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} dx \, x^3$$

which is

$$\frac14 \int_0^1 dy \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{1-y^6}}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{12} \int_0^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} = \frac{\pi}{24}$$

Comment: Ah! Ok I need to draw the sketch. But how do I know if my sketch makes any sense at all? I am not very good at graphing. Any tips?

Comment: @Artemisia: you can draw $y=x^2$, right?  And you can look sideways...right?  At least these were explicit prerequisites for Calc III at my university.  That and familiarity with the number $7$.

Comment: Well yes of course! But I mean more on the lines of tougher sketches.

Comment: @Artemisia: usually for problems like this, the sketches are no more complicated than this.  But in general, just make sure that the region is convex and makes sense sideways.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks :)

Comment: Where can I find references on the number 7, Ron?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: http://www.amazon.com/Penguin-Book-Curious-Interesting-Numbers/dp/0140261494

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I also found this: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054047/